# Use Alexa Voice Service, incl. Amazon Music

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I doesn't have much experience with Alexa Voice Service. But i hope someone can help me in this scenario. 
I just used the Raspberry Example for Alexa Voice Service in the past.

But this example hat the Limitation that Amazon Music was not supported.
Also other 3rd Party Apps which use Amazon Voice Services (e.g. Reverb) are restricted and can't use Amazon Music.

As far as i know, this is a limitation because license issues.

I have now an Use Case to develop either an Desktop App or an Web-App which should interact with Alexa, but also be possible to play Amazon Music.

My Question: Has someone experience with Alexa Voice Service, to use it, AND have access to Amazon Music? (maybe there is a solution to pay something for licence etc.(

Or is Alexa Voice Service in general restricted with Amazon Music.

Kind Regards
Stefan

Answer (score 1):

Alexa Voice Service can certainly be used with Amazon Music (and several other music providers). You need to get approval from Amazon for the music service you want to use. You can find more details by going to your AVS dashboard and looking in the entertainment tab on the product you want to enable music.